# elegant way to reload env_file within docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm using env_file settings in my docker-compose.yml.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file

```
version: "3"

services:
  my_service:
    image: nginx
    env_file:
      - .env
```

And launch the containers with `docker-compose up -d`, the container is up and running there with the environment variables defined within `.env`.

An now I changed the `.env` file from outside.

How can I tell the container on the fly to reload the new variables inside `.env`, or having to call `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate` to reclaim everything?

Comment: Does running `docker-compose up -d` without `--force-recreate` work?  (I don't know off hand whether Compose will read the `.env` file for differences from the existing container, or whether the two versions of Compose work the same way here.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, running without --force-recreate takes effect, but it will cause recreation of all affected container, which is not expected. Is there any elegant way to inject the env var merely, not having to recreate the container?

Comment: No, you must recreate the container.  (Compare to a non-container process, where similarly you must stop the process and relaunch it if you want to change its environment variables.)  On the flip side, this is completely routine; the container is just a wrapper around the process it runs, and it is very very normal to delete and recreate containers as needed.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you, so we are turning to look for a configuration service solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate
```

`--build` so that you don't use cache

It is also worth deleting the image if you just built one

You have to recreate the container if you want to reload the `env_var`, there is no way around that

You can always run `docker-compose config` to check the new values before rebuilding the container